# What is the Kotlin version of a generic array of enum values, as returned by a function?

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have a Java abstract class that includes an abstract method returning an array of generic enum values.

```java
    abstract class AbstractClass {
        ...
        abstract Enum<?>[] getAllEnumValues();
        ...
    }
```

My project has many Java classes that extend this abstract class.

```java
    class Subclass extends AbstractClass {
        enum MyEnum {
            value1,
            value2,
            value3
        }

        @Override
        protected final Enum<?>[] getAllEnumValues() {
            return MyEnum.values();
        }
    }
```

How would I do this in Kotlin? Android Studio's "Convert Java File To Kotlin File" created

```
    override fun getAllEnumValues(): Array<Enum<*>> {
        return MyEnum.values()
    }
```

but I get an error on the "return MyEnum.values()" line:

```
Type mismatch:
Required: Array<Enum<*>>
Found: Array<Subclass.MyEnum>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In Kotlin, unlike Java, arrays are invariant: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html. Simply casting to `Array<Enum<*>>` works: https://pl.kotl.in/56J7d85Lj.

Comment: Also, you don't need this method at all any more, since Kotlin provides `enumValues<Subclass.MyEnum>()` for you.

Comment: The cast to Array<Enum<*>> works great, thanks, though it does introduce a warning about an unchecked cast.